# Laravel - How to add value not listed in $fillable

Tags: laravel

In my User model I have this rule:

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];
```

And I want to add in my model one more field "role_id", that could be assigned only inside controller or model, but should be ignored in other cases.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'role_id' => $this->role_id
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$user = new User();
$user->fill([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => bcrypt($data['password'])
]);
$user->role_id = $this->role_id;
$user->save();
return $user->id;
```